# c# bound Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I have a datagridview and it is bound to a stored procedure which returns a number of result columns.

There is also a binding navigator with "Add New" button included.

If I click "Add New" button, it creates a new row in datagridview automatically, and If I leave that new row by clicking a different row. datagridview invokes "commit" or something.

so the question is 
How do I make datagridview not to commit adding a new row when I leave the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the [DataGridView.RowValidating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidating.aspx) event.

**From MSDN:**

> Use this event to perform validation on all the values of a row. If the row does not pass validation, set the [CancelEventArgs.Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) property to true. Canceling this event prevents the [RowValidated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidated.aspx), [Control.Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx), and [Control.Validated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx) events from occurring, and also prevents the user from leaving the invalid row and prevents the row from being saved to an external data source in data bound mode.

Taking an eye out the [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource_members.aspx) class might also give you ideas, since you say you're using a `BindingNavigator` along with the `DataGridView`.

Deeper details could be provided with further details.